# telerik reporting HtmlTextBox editing wizard and font-size

Tags: telerik, reporting

Is the font-size feature of the GUI editor for the HtmlTextBox broken or perhaps unimplemented?  The resulting html markup simply shows the text selection wrapped in SPAN tags, and no size change occurs at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version did you use, a text value with font size translated as following as a sample and works correctly:

```
<span style="font-size: 12pt">Test</span>
```

the control which I tested is based on "Telerik.Reporting.HtmlTextBox"

Hope that helps